# Telerik Reporting Hide Subreport

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, telerik

I'm working through the Telerik Reporting step-by-step tutorial located here:

http://www.telerik.com/documents/TelerikReporting-LearningGuide.pdf

I followed the steps precisely in the Lab: Subreports section (page 111-115).  So this lab is to display a Master-Detail report.  There is a Boolean Editor (User choose True or False) on the UI when the report is run.  The way it is supposed to work is that, when the report is loaded, both the Master report and the Detail subreport are displayed.  If the User selects False, the subreport is supposed to then be hidden.

I got the Master-Detail report to display properly.  However, after I added the functionality for hiding the subreport, when I preview the report I get the following error message:  "An error has occurred while processing SubReport 'subReport1': Specified cast is not valid".  The issue lies in the following statement:

```
(sender as Telerik.Reporting.Processing.SubReport).Visible = (bool)this.ReportParameters["ShowEmployees"].Value;
```

Therefore, as far as I can tell, this tutorial is faulty.  So the cast which I'm attempting on the right hand side of this assignment statement above is invalid.  I tried the following unsuccessfully (still get an Exception), also:

```
(sender as Telerik.Reporting.Processing.SubReport).Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(this.ReportParameters["ShowEmployees"].Value;
```

I have been trying everything for a few days now to find an alternate solution to achieve my goal, which is to hide the subreport in case the User selects False in the Boolean Editor.  Does anyone know either

1. how to resolve the cast issue in the assignment statement above, or
2. an alternate solution to hide the subreport in case the User selects False in the Boolean Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is around since v.3 of Telerik Reporting and I don't think it is updated since.

You can get reference to the main report and use the processing report parameter instead of the definition, try the following code to hide the subreport based on a report parameter (dummy code, not tested so u get an idea):

```
private void subReport1_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Processing.SubReport subReport = (Processing.SubReport)sender;
    Processing.Report mainRep = (Processing.Report)subReport.Parent;
    subReport.Visible = (bool)mainRep.Parameters["ShowEmployees"].Value;
}
```

See here for more info: http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-parameters-programmatic-control.html

Comment: Thank you silverchair for your proposed solution.  However, I tried this, and it throws an Exception on the second statement in the method body:  Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DetailSection' to type 'Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report'  I understand your approach and afterwards attempted to make modifications and to use the information in the link you provided.  But I still have not been able to resolve the problem.

Comment: I've told you the code is not tested. Change the cast to this instead:
Processing.Report mainRep = (Processing.Report)subReport.Report;

Comment: I know that the code you initially provided was not tested.  Regarding the modification you suggested this morning, I had actually tried that yesterday; but at that time I had neglected to note that it's necessary to hit the "Preview" button after toggling the True/False.  This is indeed the solution.  Thank you very much for your assistance.